# Why isn't Kaniko able to push multi-stage Docker Image?

Tags: dockerfile, gitlab-ci, kaniko

Building the following Dockerfile on GitLab CI using Kaniko, result in the error `error pushing image: failed to push to destination eu.gcr.io/stritzke-enterprises/eliah-speech-server:latest: Get https://eu.gcr.io/...: exit status 1`

If I remove the first `FROM`, `RUN` and `COPY --from` statements from the Dockerfile, the Docker Image is built and pushed as expected. If I execute the Kaniko build using Docker on my local machine everything works as expected. I execute other Kaniko builds and pushed on the same GitLab CI runner with the same GCE Service Account credentials.

What is going wrong with the GitLab CI based Kaniko build?

### Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest as alpine

RUN apk add -U --no-cache ca-certificates

FROM scratch

COPY --from=alpine /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

COPY binaries/speech-server /speech-server

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/speech-server"]
CMD ["serve", "-t", "$GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
```

#### GitLab CI build stage

```
buildDockerImage:
  stage: buildImage
  dependencies:
    - build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  variables:
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /secret.json
  script:
    - echo "$GCR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY" > /secret.json
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $DOCKER_IMAGE:latest -v debug
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
```

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? I can build multi-stage images without problems, so I assume the issue for you was credentials.

Comment: Eight months after asking, I definitely agree with your assumption. Posted an answer to maybe help diagnosing issues of other people who come here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [tdensmore pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53578399/why-isnt-kaniko-able-to-push-multi-stage-docker-image#comment-101015049) this was most likely an authentication issue.

So for everyone who has come here, the following Dockerfile and Kaniko call work just fine.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest as ubuntu

RUN echo "Foo" > /foo.txt

FROM ubuntu:latest

COPY --from=ubuntu /foo.txt /

CMD ["/bin/cat", "/foo.txt"]
```

The `Dockerfile` can be built by running

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/workspace gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest --context /workspace --no-push
```